# jQuery Remove string from string

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I am trying to remove a string from a string in jQuery.

Here is the string:

```
username1, username2 and username3 like this post.
```

I would like to remove `username1,` from this list.
I tried adding the list to an array using `.split(', ')` but I got an error. I'm assuming the error is because not every word has a comma after it.

I always want to remove the fist item from the list. `username1` is just an example username. The first item will always be the username of the currently logged in user if they have liked this post.

I have tried:

```
  var updated_list = $('#post_like_list').html().replace('username1, ', '');
  $('#post_like_list').html(updated_list);
```

But that didn't update the list. It does however update the list when using `.text()` instead of `.html()` but I have links inside the list which I need to preserve.

Comment: Does this string start as an array in JS or what? Based on the question at this point the answer could be: .replace('username1, ', '') but I doubt that's what you're after...

Comment: Please post relevant code in your question. If you're getting an error, the provide the code you're using that gives the error.

Comment: You have to clarify: Is `username1` always the same? Do you always want to remove the *first* name or do you want to remove a specific name? And this is not a jQuery question, it is a JavaScript question.

Comment: post some example html and i'm sure someone will be able to figure this out.  we've only got 1/2 of the equation at the moment.

Answer (score 185, accepted):

pretty sure you just want the plain old replace function.  use like this:

```
myString.replace('username1','');
```

i suppose if you want to remove the trailing comma do this instead:

```
myString.replace('username1,','');
```

edit:

here is your site specific code:

```
jQuery("#post_like_list-510").text().replace(...)
```

Comment: i tried that and got the error(firebug) jQuery("#post_like_list-510").replace is not a function

Comment: @carl, thats because the myString variable is just a string, not a jquery object.  so do jQuery("#post_like_list-510").text().replace(...)

Comment: you probably want jQuery('#post_like_list-510').val().replace(...)

Comment: @Carl markham: The function is a string function, not a jQuery function.

Comment: @matei, val() won't return the expected result on an object like a div or span if i recall correctly.

Answer (score 20):

To add on nathan gonzalez answer, please note you need to assign the replaced object after calling `replace` function since it is not a mutator function:

```
myString = myString.replace('username1','');
```

Answer (score 9):

If you just want to remove "username1" you can use a simple replace.

`name.replace("username1,", "")`

or you could use split like you mentioned.

```
var name = "username1, username2 and username3 like this post.".split(",")[1];      
$("h1").text(name);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/AcnBT/1/) example

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the text "username1" is just a placeholder for what will eventually be an actual username. Assuming that,

- If the username is **not** allowed to have spaces, then just search for everything before the first space or comma (thus finding both "u1 likes this" and "u1, u2, and u3 like this").
- If it **is** allowed to have a space, it would probably be easier to wrap each username in it's own `span` tag server-side, before sending it to the client, and then just working with the span tags.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure nobody answer your question to your exact terms, you want it for dynamic text

```
var newString = myString.substring( myString.indexOf( "," ) +1, myString.length );
```

It takes a substring from the first comma, to the end

Comment: Works nice! I just replaced 'str' with 'myString' for working solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I coded for removing backslash using jQuery.

```
// Remove backslash from menu
let selector = jQuery('.crm-submenu-manage-invoices a');

// Get html
let stringRemove = selector.html();

// Remove backslash
stringRemove = stringRemove.replace('\\', '');

// Push back to selector
selector.html(stringRemove);
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Shuvo's answer ... I needed to remove the title from an excerpt and used the following:

a.title is the text I wanted removed.
span.excerpt is where I wanted it removed FROM

```
var title=$('a.title').text();
let selector = jQuery('span.excerpt');
let stringRemove = selector.html();
stringRemove = stringRemove.replace(title, '');
selector.html(stringRemove);
```

Comment: Why are you using a mix of `$` and `jQuery`?