# javascript variable contains instead of equals

Tags: javascript, variables

in a javascript if...else statement, instead of checking if a variable equals (==) a value, is it possible to check if a variable includes a value?

```
var blah = unicorns are pretty;
if(blah == 'unicorns') {};       //instead of doing this,
if(blah includes 'unicorns') {}; //can i do this?
```

also, the word it includes should be the FIRST word of the variable. Thanks!!!

Comment: And a "word" is the character sequence form the beginning of the string to the first space? What about `"unicornsuperpowers are great"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(blah.indexOf('unicorns') == 0) {
    // the string "unicorns" was first in the string referenced by blah.
}

if(blah.indexOf('unicorns') > -1) {
    // the string "unicorns" was found in the string referenced by blah.
}
```

[`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

To remove the first occurrence of a string:

```
blah = blah.replace('unicorns', '');
```

Comment: @ThomasLai: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095000/jquery-remove-string-from-string.

Answer (score 2):

If by "first word", you mean a character sequence from the beginning of the string to the first space, then this will do it:

```
if  ((sentence + ' ').indexOf('unicorns ') === 0) {
    //         note the trailing space ^
}
```

If instead of a space it can be any white-space character, you should use a regular expression:

```
if (/^unicorns(\s|$)/.test(sentence)) {
    // ...
}

// or dynamically
var search = 'unicorns';
if (RegExp('^' + search + '(\\s|$)').test(sentence)) {
    // ...
}
```

You can also use the special word-boundary character, depending on the language you want to match:

```
if (/^unicorns\b/.test(sentence)) {
    // ...  
}
```

[More about regular expressions.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

---

Related question:

- [How to check if a string "StartsWith" another string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646628/javascript-startswith)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a quick regex test:

```
if (/unicorns/.test(blah)) {
  // has "unicorns"
}
```

Comment: To check the *first* word you would need `if (/^unicorns/.test(blah))`